# Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Found no access plan for a pattern relationship in a connected component. This must not happen

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have setup a Neo4j database using Docker. I use the version 3.4.1 Enterprise with all default configuration.

I've added a unique constraint on a node.

```
CONSTRAINT ON (product:Product) ASSERT product.pcode IS UNIQUE
```

I then try to run a `MERGE` query

```
MERGE (u:Profile{pid:'123'})<-[:SHOPS_AT]-(:Store)-[:SELLS]->(:Product{pcode:'pcode-1234'})
```

However, I get the following error:
`Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Found no access plan for a pattern relationship in a connected component. This must not happen.`

As you can tell, the exception message is not helpful at all. I noticed that if I remove the constraint it works.

I tried against another Neo4j instance that's deployed in a VM, same version, Enterprise edition, with the same constraint and it passes!!!

Anybody had a similar experience? I didn't find a lot by Googling. Reason why I get this error?

Comment: Yes, the error can be repeated. I think this is a bug. It is worth opening the issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for this buggy behavior.

However, even if the bug did not exist, you probably do not want to write the query that way. To quote the [documentation for MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) (taken from version 3.5):

> When using `MERGE` on full patterns, the behavior is that either the
>   whole pattern matches, or the whole pattern is created. `MERGE` will not
>   partially use existing patterns — it’s all or nothing. If partial
>   matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a pattern up
>   into multiple `MERGE` clauses.

That is, this query:

```
MERGE (u:Profile{pid:'123'})<-[:SHOPS_AT]-(:Store)-[:SELLS]->(:Product{pcode:'pcode-1234'})
```

can create new `Profile` and `Product` nodes -- even if either node matches an existing node -- if the *entire pattern* does not already exist.

You probably actually want to use the following query instead (which also does not cause the error you encountered):

```
MERGE (u:Profile{pid:'123'})
MERGE (p:Product{pcode:'pcode-1234'})
MERGE (u)<-[:SHOPS_AT]-(:Store)-[:SELLS]->(p)
```